# How to write a Regex Multi lines?

Tags: regex

I try to find the solution by myself but that is 2 days i'm trying for finally give up :(

I have some files log with row like below and I need to extract datetime, editor error and the MD5 and insert them in file like that:
Datetime;editor error;MD5

Actually I'm using the following commands but it's not enought, some data missing because my regexp not take chariot returns...

Commands:

```
grep -oPh '201[8-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]T[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].*[a-f0-9]{32}' all_merged_draft > date_editor_md5_draft && 
grep -oPh '^201[8-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]T[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]' date_editor_md5_draft > date_draft && 
grep -oPh '[a-f0-9]{32}$' date_editor_md5_draft > md5_draft && 
grep -oPh '";".*";"' date_editor_md5_draft > editor_draft && 
sed -ir '{s/^";"//;s/";"$//g}' editor_draft && 
sed -ir 's/T/ /' date_draft && 
paste -d ';' date_draft editor_draft md5_draft > date_editor_md5_final
```

Sample of my logs:

```
"2019-04-19T00:01:55+02:00";"error webservice website.com";"array (
  0 =&gt; &#039;d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8478e&#039;,
  1 =&gt; &#039;&#039;,
  2 =&gt; &#039;&#039;,
  3 =&gt; &#039;&#039;,
  4 =&gt; &#039;&#039;,
  5 =&gt; &#039;&#039;,
)"
"2019-04-19T00:02:05+02:00";"error webservice website2.com";" =&gt; 12150078c123cb2c496bda549c64b129"
"2019-04-19T00:02:23+02:00";"error webservice website3.com";"178c59ab048e885d8f0e2992f4471b43 =&gt; NOMATCH"
"2019-04-19T00:02:53+02:00";"error webservice website5.com";"array (
  0 =&gt; &#039;d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8787e&#039;,
  1 =&gt; &#039;&#039;,
  2 =&gt; &#039;&#039;,
  3 =&gt; &#039;&#039;,
  4 =&gt; &#039;&#039;,
  5 =&gt; &#039;&#039;,
)"
"2019-04-19T03:03:04+02:00";"websitexxx.com webservice Hash nomatch";" =&gt; 12150052c847cb2c496bda549c64b129"
"2019-04-19T03:03:22+02:00";"  error";"233c59dc048e885d8f0e2992f4471b43 =&gt; NOMATCH"
"2019-04-19T03:05:00+02:00";"website8.com webservice error";"Response = array (
  0 =&gt; &#039;&#039;,
) for hash = a38267ce82b711165d3979fe0ed16ba6"
```

I need a regex parsing on multiple lines...

Finally my file must be like that:

```
2019-04-19 00:01:55;error webservice website.com;d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8478e

2019-04-19 00:02:05;error webservice website2.com;12150078c123cb2c496bda549c64b129

2019-04-19 00:02:23;error webservice website3.com;178c59ab048e885d8f0e2992f4471b43

2019-04-19 00:02:53;error webservice website5.com;d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8787e

2019-04-19 03:03:04;websitexxx.com webservice Hash nomatch;12150052c847cb2c496bda549c64b129

2019-04-19 03:03:22;website8.com webservice error;a38267ce82b711165d3979fe0ed16ba6
```

Comment: Why do you not want `2019-04-19 03:03:22; error;233c59dc048e885d8f0e2992f4471b43` ?

Comment: `sed -n ':a;/"$/!{N;b a};s/\n//g;s/^"\([0-9-]*\)T\([0-9:]*\)[^;]*;"\([^"]*\).*\([0-9a-f]\{32\}\).*$/\1 \2;\3;\4\n/p' <all_merged_draft >date_editor_md5_final`